# Displaying HTML, CSS and Javascript with Martini

Tags: frameworks, go, web-frameworks, martini

I'm trying to build a chatroom using Martini.

I put together some HTML, CSS and JS using Bootstrap, and now I want to display it using Martini. 
I'm able to display a "Hello world" index.html file without much trouble, but when I replace index.html file with the code I want it to render (the chat room layout), it tries calling the js/ and css/ files using GET requests and fails.

Specifically, this is the output :

```
[martini] listening on :3000
[martini] Started GET /
[martini] Completed 200 OK in 570.573us
[martini] Started GET /index.html
[martini] Completed 200 OK in 1.188084ms
[martini] Started GET /js/chatclient.js
[martini] Completed 404 Not Found in 614.137us
[martini] Started GET /js/bootstrap.min.js
[martini] Completed 404 Not Found in 417.855us
[martini] Started GET /css/bootstrap.min.css
[martini] Completed 404 Not Found in 440.463us
```

Any advice on how I can get the Javascript to work? From a simple Google search I couldn't find anything regarding being able to render CSS and JS using Martini, which is why I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, got it -

Its a simple

```
m.Use(martini.Static(<path to assets>))
```